# Win32 Critical Section vs Mutex Performance

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, mutex, critical-section

I wrote a small program to compare the performance of Critical Section vs Mutex in Windows.

On the tests I ran, acquiring Critical Section seems to be Slower :O Can anybody explain why both things take almost the same amount of time, and what is happening internally.

This is the timer I used - http://cplus.about.com/od/howtodothingsi2/a/timing.htm

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include "h_timer.h"
#include<WinBase.h>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<stdio.h>

#define MAX_THREADS 2000  
//Comment and Uncomment this to enable/disable critialSection / Mutex
#define CRIT 1

using namespace std;

HANDLE Mutex;
CRITICAL_SECTION critSection;
DWORD WINAPI Contention( LPVOID );

int main( void )
{
    HANDLE Thread[MAX_THREADS];
    DWORD ThreadID;
    int i;

#ifdef CRIT
//create a critical section
InitializeCriticalSection(&critSection);
#else

    // Create a mutex with no initial owner
    Mutex = CreateMutex( NULL, FALSE,NULL);

#endif

    // Create worker threads

CStopWatch timer, tempTimer;
timer.startTimer();
    for( i=0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++ )
    {
        Thread[i] = CreateThread( NULL,
                     0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)Contention,NULL,0,&ThreadID);
    }
    WaitForMultipleObjects(MAX_THREADS, Thread, TRUE, INFINITE);

    timer.stopTimer();
    cout<<endl<<"Elapsed Time:"<<timer.getElapsedTime();
    cin.get();
    // Close thread and mutex handles

    for( i=0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++ )
    CloseHandle(Thread[i]);

    CloseHandle(Mutex);
    return 0;
}


DWORD WINAPI Contention( LPVOID lpParam )
{
    #ifdef CRIT
EnterCriticalSection(&critSection);
//printf("ThreadId: %d\n",GetCurrentThreadId());
//printf("Let's try Again. %d\n\n", GetCurrentThreadId());
LeaveCriticalSection(&critSection);

#else
// lpParam not used in this example
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpParam);
    DWORD dwCount=0, dwWaitResult;

    // Request ownership of mutex.
    dwWaitResult = WaitForSingleObject(
            ghMutex, // handle to mutex
            INFINITE); // no time-out interval
        dwCount++;
    ReleaseMutex(ghMutex);
#endif

return TRUE;
}
```

For 2000 threads, on a Quad Core HPZ210, both take roughly 1.5 secs.

Comment: Wall time is not the important thing when it comes to scalability of a synchronization primitive.  You also don't hold the lock for any length of time, so you don't have any contention at all.  This is a terrible test.

Comment: Oh, Okay. What's a better way to do this test? I wanted to see which of the two takes more time to acquire/release etc. Pls note this is not wall time (or is it?) - the timing is done using the QueryPerformanceFrequency/Counter system calls. Thanks!

Comment: Do some non-trivial task inside the lock.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think there are two factors:

Mainly - Your program is dominated by thread creation overhead.  You are creating and destroying 2000 threads, and only accessing the mutex/CS once per thread.  The time spent creating threads swamps the difference in lock/unlock times.

Also - You may not be testing the use case that these locks were optimized for.  Try spawning two threads that each try to access the mutex/CS thousands of times.

Comment: +1 This continual creation/termination/detruction of thread objects is done so often that I wonder where the idea came from. I presume some poisonous textbook is responsible. Sometimes, it seems that the whole SO is riddled with threads that add two integers and then terminate, just so that the 'main' thread can wait with 'join'.  God help us :(

Comment: But... multithreaded programs are faster!  I LOL'ed for real, great comment.

Comment: I've spent years trying to stop Delphi developers from starting threads and waiting for them to terminate with TThread.WaitFor, (Delphi 'Join'), and instead use sane signaling with queues and messages to threads and pools that last the lifetime of the app.  Now, a new generation of langauges and developers are going down the same rabbit-warren with Java and C#.  It just gets so fustrating - multi-threading should be easy, high-performance and actual fun, not some recurring nightmare of synchronization, deadlocks and 'HELP! how can I terminate my threads'.

Answer (score 10):

Critical sections are a hybrid of user-mode and kernel-mode.  They try to keep your thread from context switching by using a spin lock (user-mode) before falling back on a more expensive semaphore (kernel-mode). This improves performance in real-world scenarios. In contrast, a mutex is purely kernel-mode and will immediately wait, performing a context switch.

By having 100% contention between 2000 threads, you've made it so the critical sections will almost certainly spin as much as possible, eating up CPU, before finally doing exactly what the mutex does and performing a wait in kernel-mode. So it makes sense for them to be slower in this situation.

And what japreiss said. Thread creation is very slow.